# How can I change one or more line breaks to something in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I change one or more line breaks to something in ruby?

```
article.content.gsub(/\n/, "<br />")
```

above code will change every 1 line break to `<br />` tag, however, I want to change one or more \n to `<br />` tag. In that way, continuous line breaks with empty lines will be substitued into a single `<br />` tag. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
article.content.gsub(/\n+/, "<br />")
```

Note the plus sign after the `\n`. That will change any sequence of one or more newlines to a single `<br>`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That worked! By the way, is there a way to wrap each line with `<li>each line</li>`?? I gave `<br />` just as an example, and now I realize that I need to separate each line by `<li>` tag... ignoring empty line with no `<li>` tag...

Comment: @user482594: There are lots of ways to do that (just ask it as a question if you want to see how many) but, off the top of my head, the most straight forward and easiest to understand would probably be `s.split(/\n+/).map{ |x| '<li>' + x + '</li>' }.join` where `s` is your string. You'd probably want to HTML encode `x` inside the block as well.

Comment: Thank you. That did work. I actually had to use it like `s.split(/\n+/).reject{|w| w.strip==""}.map{|x| '<li>' + x.strip + '</li>'}.join` for the case which a single space gets left in lines. But that was a lot of help I got from you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It also might be helpful to quickly test Ruby regular expressions against sample data using [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/).